# Самый быстрый способ найти все аннаграммы

Tags: java, алгоритм

Написал метод который находит все анаграммы из списка переданных слов. В котором первым шагом - я просто фильтрую по длине слова, второй шаг это - фильтрация по чексумме которую я вычисляю просто суммирую все `chars`, третий этап это уже точная проверка, в массиве (indexes) хранится количество каждой буквы подскажите что можно улучшить в этом алгоритме или может я вообще не тем путем иду и есть что то быстрее?

Comment: @anton-sorokin для вашего предыдущего ответа если initalString = "ksmk" и добавить в массив слово "mskk" он не найдет это слово

Comment: Все, понял. Я думал, что анаграмма - это когда слово написано в обратно порядке.

Comment: Список слов постоянный, а word меняется, так?

Comment: @Mbo И то и другое не постоянное

Comment: т.е. каждый раз передаётся список слов и одно слово, к которому в списке нужно найти анаграммы?

Comment: @Mbo да, каждый раз и слово и список разный

Answer (score 2):

Для сравнения слова с одноразовым списком нет смысла разбивать на несколько стадий.

Отсортировать буквы слова `word => dorw`

Перебирать слова списка по порядку, смотреть длину, если совпадает - отсортировать буквы, сравнить с искомым словом.

Comment: Сама сортировка займет много времени, а тут еще и сравнение делать, как это мжоет быть быстрее моего варианта

Comment: Сортировка символов в слове (не слов между собой) - очень быстрая. Собственно, Anton Sorokin уже реализовал этот метод, стоит попробовать. Могу даже предположить, что больше времени уйдёт на преобразование слов в CharArray, чем на саму сортировку

Comment: String это и есть char[], он просто возвращает этот используемый массив. А если использовать charAt то он вовсе не копирует.

Comment: Только вот String в джаве неизменяемый, поэтому для сортировки символов в слове приходится создавать новый объект другого типа, содержащий копию тела строки

Comment: да, использя native System.arrayCopy, в любом случае я поменял на charAt

Comment: charAt возвращает символ с данным индексом, но не позволяет в его записать, так ведь? Тогда в сортировке это небольшой помощник.

Comment: Как бы да, я и не сортирую

Answer (score 0):

Вот код:

```
    String[] stringArray = {"weddw", "cew", "ghr", "kov", "wev"};
    String initialWord = "wce";
    char[] word = initialWord.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(word);
    char[] secondWord;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)
        if(initialWord.length() == stringArray[i].length()) {
            secondWord = stringArray[i].toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(secondWord);
            if(Arrays.equals(word, secondWord))
                System.out.println(stringArray[i]);
        }
```

Comment: @JMas: ну что, есть какие-то замечания? И по поводу вопроса с замером скорости.

Comment: Сортировка занимает много времени, из миллиона слов мне придется отсортировать 10 000 слов, и это не будет быстро

Comment: Вам уже написали, что сортировка массива - это быстро

Comment: Сортировка как минимум log n, сортировка плюс сравнение, в момем случае я сразу сравниваю charы

Comment: log n  (точнее, nlogn) от чего берётся?

Comment: Минимальная скорость сортировки есть n log n

Comment: Затраты на сортировку `t*L*log(L)` где t - количество подходящих слов, L - длина каждого. А что Вы подразумеваете под n?